# XCTestCase error when instantiate view controller from storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I am quite new in using unit test in swift, and when i try to create unit test for measuring performance, i run into an error.

here is the code for my test case.

```
func testPerformaceFetchSearchResult(){
    //let ICD9ViewController = ICD9Controller() //this is not working since i need the IBOutlet also
    var ICD9ViewController:ICD9Controller!

    let storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType))
    ICD9ViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ICD9Controller") as! ICD9Controller
    ICD9ViewController.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: false)

    ICD9ViewController.code = "0"
    ICD9ViewController.name = ""
    ICD9ViewController.desc = ""
    ICD9ViewController.sortBy = 1
    ICD9ViewController.customPage.pageNo = 1
    ICD9ViewController.customPage.pageSize = 10

    self.measureBlock(){
        ICD9ViewController.fetchSearchResult()
    }
}
```

The error is in this line

```
ICD9ViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ICD9Controller") as! ICD9Controller
```

And the error message is

> Could not cast value of type '*appName*.ICD9Controller' (*address*) to '*appName*.ICD9Controller' (*differentAddress*)

I have read several question about XCTestCase and most of the error is could not cast value of type `_appName_.viewController` to `_appNameTests_.viewController` which is not the case for me since i have already check the target membership for my storyboard and my controller.

My question is, how do i instantiate view controller from storyboard for unit test correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling for two days, i finally found the root problem.

The problem is cast issue, there are two module with the same name which is *appName* in my case. This make xCode confused, which is why it cannot cast the view controller.

Since module name usually take product name as its source, i change the test product name and my problem finally solved.

Comment: You are a god among men, this was my exact issue. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

The view controller and storyboard should only be available on the application target and then you can use `@testable` to access it on your tests.

Check if this [post](https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-2-xcode-7-unit-testing-access/) helps you as well. Also, if this doesn't work, please try to use `NSBundle.mainBundle()` instead of the test bundle.

Comment: I agree that using `@testable` is better to restrict the access level. But to implement that, i need to change lots of part of the project which i'm inclined to do so at this stage so i stick to 'check membership' method for now. And changing the bundle still produces the same error. Thanks for the answer though!